# C program to find total number of digits

Tags: c, printf, getchar, digit

I wrote this program to find the total number of digits from a line of text entered by user. I am having error on using `getchar()`. I can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

void main() {
    char c[MAX_SIZE];
    int digit, sum, i;
    digit, i = 0;

    printf("Enter a line of characters>");
    c = getchar();
    while (c[i] != '\n') {
        digit = 0;
        if (c [i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9') {
            digit++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", digit);
}
```

I will be adding all the digits I found using sum variable. but I am getting error on `getchar()` line. HELP??

Comment: `c = getchar()` - `c` is an array (and as such is not direct-assignable regardless of the rest of this). `getchar()` returns `int`. Honestly, [you don't need an array for this task at all](https://ideone.com/kN6Btz), if the purpose is simply to count digit-chars until end-of-line or end-of-file.

Comment: `getchar` gets a single char. You should use `fgets`or something like that

Comment: ..and then you don't increment `i` in the loop.

Comment: In general, if you get an error, you should post what the error is.  That said, the comments have this covered.

Comment: okay so based of what you guys have mentioned that do not use array i wrote something without using array which is like this:
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{
 char c;
 int digit, sum;
 digit = 0;

 printf("Enter a line of characters>");
 c = getchar();
 while (c != '\n')
 {
  digit = 0;
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
  {
   digit++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", digit);
 }
 
}

i am getting "0" printed out on terminal after giving any input.

Comment: Usually you'd put your character by character input reading inside the loop rather than just reading once...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP even did bother to read the msn pages. Zero effort question not worth our time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter a "line of text" without using an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {                    // notice this signature
    int c, digits = 0, sum = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        if(isdigit(c)) {
            digits++;
            sum += c - '0';
        }
    }
    printf("%d digits with sum %d\n", digits, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `c` is of type `int`. Most of the library's character functions do not use `char` type.

**Edit:** added the sum of the digits.

Comment: That should be another question, but I have edited the answer. Note that `'0'` is also of type `int`.

Comment: (OP asked "how do I sum the digit values?)

Answer (score 0):

Weather Vane's answer is the best and simplest answer. However, for future reference, if you want to iterate (loop through) an array, it would be easier to use a for loop. Also, your main function should return an int and should look like this: `int main()`. You will need to put a `return 0;` at the end of your main function. Here is a modified version of your program that uses a for loop to loop through the character array. I used the [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) function to read a line of characters from the console. It does wait for the user to enter the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    char c[MAX_SIZE];
    int digit = 0;

    printf("Enter a line of characters>");
    gets(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == '\n') break; // this line checks to see if we have reached the end of the line. If so, exit the for loop (thats what the "break" statment does.)

        //if (isdigit(c[i])) // uncomment this line and comment or delete the one below to use a much easier method to check if a character is a digit.
        if (c [i]>= '0' && c[i] <= '9')
        {
            digit++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", digit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you Master Codeon. much appreciated you help.

Comment: `gets` is so dangerous it was made obsolete, so ***very bad*** to recommend using it. And `main` is the *one* function not required to return a value. Someone has upvoted this answer. I would have downvoted, but I never vote on answers to a question where I have given one.

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: Granted, I used it for simplicity sake. I am pretty sure the OP isn't caring about stuff like fact that `gets` is susceptible to a buffer overflow attack and such. I never knew that main could be void. I knew in C# it was possible, but I thought that you couldn't do that in C++. You learn something new every day!

Comment: Is is not that `main` can be `void`, it is that an absence of the return value in `main` is tolerated by the compiler. But only for `main`.

Comment: Don't recommend `gets` just because you think OP won't care. Probably cares very much that correct code is advised.

Comment: Oh, I see. never noticed that. I just by habit, set it up to return an int, and put a `return 0;` at the end. True, but in the end, I was going for simplicity's sake. If I were to do it the correct way, I would have to allocate a buffer and use `fgetc` to read the characters. Then, while in the loop, do all my bounds checking, and checks for EOF, and null characters and such. Although, I like your answer best because it doesn't use an array of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

An easy of getting the number of digits in an integer is the use of log10() function which is defined in math.h header. Consider this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    system("clear");

    unsigned int i, sum = 0, numberOfDigits;
    puts("Enter a number");
    scanf("%u", &i);
    numberOfDigits = (int) (log10(x) + 1);

    system("clear");

    while(i != 0) {
        sum += (i % 10);
        i /= 10;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "The sum is %i\n", sum);
    fflush(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```